# MVC Call Controller Method without opening a new page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a method called output in my controller class. I want to send a parameter to it when I change selected items in my dropdownlist, then make it run a certain SQL query depending on that parameter, and have it return the results. The thing is, I don't want to open a new page when returning the results, I just want to maybe display the results of that query in an alert, not open a URL to run the method. This is my current javascript, the method is an ActionResult called output and has a parameter called test, which is a string.

```
    <script src="../../Content/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function () {

        jQuery("#SelectedCentre").change(function () {
            var _this = jQuery(this);
            var selectedCentre = _this.val();
            window.location.href = "/Centres/output?test=" + selectedCentre;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: window.location.href is a JS navigation method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make an ajax call for that:

jQuery(function () {

```
    jQuery("#SelectedCentre").change(function () {
        var _this = jQuery(this);
        var selectedCentre = _this.val();
        jQuery.get("/Centres/output?test=" + selectedCentre, function(results){
         // do something with results here
        });
    });
});
```

**EDIT to answer your question in the comments:**

In your controller return an object of type json, like this:

```
 var data = new List<SelectListItem>
                           {
                               new SelectListItem
                                   {
                                       Text = "Test1",
                                       Value = "1"
                                   },
                                new SelectListItem
                                   {
                                       Text = "Test2",
                                       Value = "2"
                                   }
                           };
            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

And update your jQuery code to deal with a json object and create the options:

```
$.getJSON("/Centres/output?test=" + selectedCentre, function (results) {
    $.each(results, function (i, item) {
        $("<option>", { text: item.Text, value: item.Value }).appendTo("#mySelect");
    });
});
```

Comment: if the results of the query are stored in a List<SelectListItem>, is there a way to make and populate a dropdownlist (or <select>) inside that same jquery/javascript? Thanks for the speedy answer, worked PERFECTLY first time!

Answer (score 2):

you want to use JQuery's get method.

```
 jQuery.get('Centres/output?test=' + selectedCentre, function (result) {
     alert(result);
 });
```

You can do anything with the result you want as long as it is JSON. If it is HTML, you can push it into an existing element on the page.

Also why aren't you using the $ that jquery gives you?

Comment: I'm super new to web development, and have had to learn html, css, javascript, jquery, prototype, ajax all in one go, and all in the context of mvc. So i don't fully understand all of this stuff yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.get("/Centres/output?test=" + selectedCentre, function(results){
         // do something with results here
console.log(results);
        });
```